# String matching with other string and output array

Tags: scala

I have a requirement where i have 2 string like below

```
val data1 = ("42881644070,13.04148,80.096043,32,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435381]#42881685433,13.057927,80.127096,45,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435383]#42881685434,13.057927,80.127096,35,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435384]")

val data2 = ("42881644070#43848058544#43847944680#43849252675#43849251662#43849943435#43850472762")
```

I wanted to compare data 2 values to data1 1st item which is id and seperator between item is # here.Also the output should be only the items which is not matching with data2.

Here the output should be Array[String]

```
Array(42881685433,13.057927,80.127096,45,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435383], 42881685434,13.057927,80.127096,35,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435384])
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you tried ?

Comment: I tried 
```data1.split("#").flatMap(_.split(",").filter {_.intersect(data2_splt).isEmpty})```

But it is wrong its not filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```scala
val data1 = "42881644070,13.04148,80.096043,32,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435381]#42881685433,13.057927,80.127096,45,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435383]#42881685434,13.057927,80.127096,35,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435384]"

val data2 = "42881644070#43848058544#43847944680#43849252675#43849251662#43849943435#43850472762"

val array1 = data1.split("#")
val array2 = data2.split("#")

val res = array1.filterNot(elem => array2.contains(elem.split(",").head))
println(res.mkString(","))
// Displays
// 42881685433,13.057927,80.127096,45,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435383],42881685434,13.057927,80.127096,35,2019-05-01 12:32:00,[32435384]
```